# Python Multiprocessing Process Doesn't Start

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Exploring Python's multiprocessing module, I created a simple toy program that starts a background service. The service simulates running some periodic background operation, while also responding to signals from the parent process.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import queue
import time


def service(q: mp.Queue):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    while True:
        try:
            s = q.get(True, 0.01)
            print('$ Input Received')
            if s == 'quit':
                print('$ Quitting')
                break
            print(f'$ Input Text={s}')
        except queue.Empty:
            pass

        end = time.perf_counter()
        if end - start > 1.0:
            print('$ TICK')
            start = end


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = mp.Queue()
    proc = mp.Process(target=service, args=(q,))
    proc.start()
    while proc.is_alive():
        text = input('>')
        q.put(text)
        if text == 'quit':
            break

    proc.join()
```

It sort of works, but there are 2 phenomena that puzzle me.

1. The subprocess does not seem to start until the first `input` operation completes. After this initial stall, it runs as expected in the background outputting its tick message.
2. The input received by the subprocess via the queue is often empty or incomplete. I have observed that this happens when the subprocess `print`s after keyboard input has been made, i.e. `print` seems to erase any buffered keyboard input. Any input dispatched via the enter key before the latest *TICK* is received by the subprocess and printed as expected.

If anyone could shed some light on/explain these phenomena to me I would be greatly obliged.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I played with your code a bit and it seems that the `print()`ing of the `'$ TICK'` messes up the input. The code below gets the input correctly and stops when you type "quit", but it doesn't print the `'$ TICK'`

I hope this helps you in the right direction.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import queue
import sys


def service(q: mp.Queue):
    while True:
        try:
            s = q.get(True, 0.01)
            print('$ Input Received')
            if s == 'quit':
                print('$ Quitting')
                break
            print(f'$ Input Text={s}')
        except queue.Empty:
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = mp.Queue()

    proc = mp.Process(target=service, args=(q,))
    proc.start()
    while proc.is_alive():
        text = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
        q.put(text)
        if text == 'quit':
            break

    proc.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I had already surmised that print is sabotaging input (see original question). More interested in knowing why this happens, and most importantly, why the subprocess stalls until the first input is made.

Comment: @chili sure, hope it helps. For me, the process didn't seem to stall. But versus your code, I changed it to use ```sys.stdin.readline().strip()```, so that may have solved that bit of it.